# symfony 3 reload ajax form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

Hi I don't find the correct syntax to do this ..

I have two form in 2 different tab in the homepage.

`form2` is a create field of one field to `form 1`

I submit `form1` with AJAX

```
$('#form-indirizzo').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form =$(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:form.attr('method'),
            url:form.attr('action'),
            data:form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              ->  $("#form-stufa").load(location.href+" #form-stufa>*","");
            },
            error: function(){

              }

        });
    });
```

it saves the data but I want also go to `form1` tab ( form1 have id=form-stufa) and reload it... I try  this

`$("#form-stufa").load(location.href+" #form-stufa>*","");`

to reload but don't work..

can help

My twig file :

```
-page-wall -->
                            <div id="profile-page-wall" class="stufe col s12 m12">
                                <!-- profile-page-wall-share -->
                                <div id="profile-page-wall-share" class="row">
                                    <div class="col s12">
                                        <ul class="tabs tab-profile z-depth-1 light-blue">
                                            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="white-text waves-effect waves-light active" href="#UpdateStatus"><i class="mdi-editor-border-color"></i> REGISTRA STUFA</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="white-text waves-effect waves-light" href="#AddPhotos"><i class="mdi-image-camera-alt"></i> Lista Stufe registrate</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="white-text waves-effect waves-light" href="#CreateAlbum"><i class="mdi-image-photo-album"></i> Aggiungi Indirizzo</a>
                                            </li>                      
                                        </ul>
                                        <!-- UpdateStatus-->
                                        <div id="UpdateStatus" class="tab-content col s12  grey lighten-4">
                                            {{form_start(form,{'attr':{'id':'form-stufa'}})}}
                                            {{form_widget(form)}}
                                              <input id="salva_stufa" class=" btn" type="submit" value="Salva" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            {{form_end(form)}}
                                        </div>


                                    </div>


                                    <!-- AddPhotos -->
                                    <div id="AddPhotos" class="tab-content col s12  grey lighten-4">


                                    </div>
                                    <!-- CreateAlbum -->
                                    <div id="CreateAlbum" class="tab-content col s12  grey lighten-4">
                                        {{form_start(form_indirizzo,{'attr':{'id':'form-indirizzo'}})}}

                                         {{form_widget(form_indirizzo)}}
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col s12 m12 right-align">
                                                <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
                                                <input id="salva_indirizzo" class=" btn" type="submit" value="Salva" />

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        {{form_end(form_indirizzo)}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

MY route :

[image]

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="youURL#form-stufa"},500);` Do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `$("#form-stufa")` if you want to click on success tab then call `click` event of JQ.

```
  $('#form-indirizzo').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form =$(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:form.attr('method'),
            url:form.attr('action'),
            data:form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
              // For redirection
              setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="youURL#form-stuf‌​a"},500);
              // This is for click the tab after success callback.
              //setTimeout(function(){$("#form-stufa").click()},500);
            },
            error: function(){

              }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Update your question while posting an answer to tell the developers what you have tried.

Comment: What is your localhost URL to access your web page? It's pretty simple just pass your URL nothing else.

Comment: my path: http://localhost:8000/    or localhost/name_project/web/app.php

Comment: i try this : setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="localhost:8000"},500);  and also {window.location.href="localhost:8000#form-stufa"},500);

Comment: You don't add your folder name in URL like `localhost:8000/yourFolderName/etc` Can you please share your web page screenshot. Are you accessing your web page using root `URL`?

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="FullURL/yourFile.php#form-stufa"}‌​,500);`